# Direct and inverse proportionality

Tags: arithmetic

Let $x$ is directly proportional to $y$ and inversely proportional to $z$.

From above condition we have that: $x=\alpha y$ and $x=\dfrac{\beta}{z}$.

Does it follow that $x=k\dfrac{y}{z}$ where $k$ is some constant?

If it is true could anyone explain how it follows?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753852/joint-proportionality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $x$ being directly proportional to $y$ and $z$ separately imply that $x$ is directly proportional to $yz?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4323252/21813) $\quad$ If there is no other relationship between $y$ and $z,$ then the $\alpha$ that you write cannot be a real number; if $x=f(y,z),$ then $\alpha=g(z).$

Answer (score 0):

As you said,

$$
x=\alpha y
$$

and

$$
x=\frac{\beta}{z}
$$

Multiplying the two equations we get,

$$
x^2 = \alpha \beta\frac{y}{z}
$$

So, the correct relation is,

> $$
> x=k_1 \sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}
> $$

Now, let us suppose that $x=k_2\frac{y}{z}$ is also true.

Then,

$${\frac{y}{z}} = k_3$$

which is false since you placed no constraints on $y$ and $z$.

Comment: I think that you got something else.

Comment: Yes, because you premise was false.

Comment: Are you stating that my statement is false?